# How do I serialize a Boost scoped_array using Boost serialization?

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize a Boost `scoped_array` using Boost serialization but the compiler (VS2008) is giving me the following error message:

```
error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'boost::scoped_array<T>'
```

How do I serialize a `scoped_array`?  Is there a Boost library that I should be including for this?

Answer (score 1):

Guess not. The `scoped_ptr` and `scoped_array` are designed for keeping track of pointers in a local scope.

> The scoped_ptr template is a simple solution for simple needs. It supplies a basic "resource acquisition is initialization" facility, without shared-ownership or transfer-of-ownership semantics. Both its name and enforcement of semantics (by being noncopyable) signal its intent to retain ownership solely within the current scope.

Having the content serialized and read back later seems to be against the intent of the class.

Comment: Thank you for the information Bo.  Unfortunately I was not in charge of determining what type of variables should be used, so I had no choice but to serialize the values contained within these data structures.  I have posted a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Serialise the array itself, not a memory-managing wrapper around it.

Comment: Awesome. I have since figured out _how_ to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I ended up using (symmetric -- works for saving and loading):

```
void myClass::serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version)
{
    ar & myScopedArraySIZE;

    // Only gets called during loading
    if (Archive::is_loading::value)
    {
        myScopedArray.reset(new ColourPtr[myScopedArraySIZE]);
    }

    for (uint i = 0; i < myScopedArraySize; i++)
    {
        ar & myScopedArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it not be
ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(myScopedArraySIZE);   
and  
ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(myScopedArray[i]);  ?